# Converting Chrome Extension to Manifest V3 - Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Hi I am trying to convert [this Chrome Extension](https://github.com/adida/Chrome-Extension-Firestore-Exampe/blob/master/background.js) to manifest V3. I worked for a few hours and finally one by one got the error messages taken care of but now when I refresh to extension and open the service worker console nothing is printed. Likewise, nothing is added to the actual Firestore database. I have the updated code below. Thanks in advance!

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "QuickChat",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chat quick!",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": 
    "background.js", 
    "type": "module"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe- 
inline' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com;"
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-app.js';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDoc, doc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-firestore.js";

// The app's Firebase configuration(change it to fit your database).
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<auth-domain>",
  databaseURL: "<db-url>",    
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  storageBucket: "<storage-bucket>",
  messagingSenderId: "<messagingSender-Id>",
  appId: "<app-id>",
  measurementId: "<measurement-Id>"
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

// Write data
// This code is from : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");

(async () => {
  await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "SF"), {
    name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 860000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "norcal"] });
  await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "LA"), {
    name: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 3900000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "socal"] });
  await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "DC"), {
    name: "Washington, D.C.", state: null, country: "USA",
    capital: true, population: 680000,
    regions: ["east_coast"] });
  await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "TOK"), {
    name: "Tokyo", state: null, country: "Japan",
    capital: true, population: 9000000,
    regions: ["kanto", "honshu"] });
  await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "BJ"), {
    name: "Beijing", state: null, country: "China",
    capital: true, population: 21500000,
    regions: ["jingjinji", "hebei"] });




  // Read data.
  // This code is from : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
  const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot to import the `setDoc` from the `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-firestore.js` but you are using it hence there are no documents getting stored in the DB which results in nothing being printed. Let me know if this worked after `setDoc` import.

Comment: And please mask you firebase credentials while asking, especially on the public sites like this one it could cost you if someone misused the credentials. I have edited the question with removing the credentials.

Comment: @RohitKharche I imported setDoc and still the same characteristics

Comment: @RohitKharche I didn't have much luck with that code snippet. I got this error right off the bat: "Top-level await is disallowed in service workers." and beyond that the variable results isn't used anywhere so I'm confused as to its purpose

Comment: I have update the [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/4eNtLTPdKs) can you check once again ?

Comment: It immediately gets this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined" If I change that line to this: "const firebase = initializeApp(config);" and got this error next: "Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined" I'm struggling to properly define Firebase because you can no longer do it the same way and Manifest V2. I also came across this which I'm not sure if it applies to this project: "https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/634"

Comment: @RussellHertel Found any solution? I am also getting `Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available`.

Comment: @NitishParkar Yeah I just found a simple Manifest V2 chrome extension and got it to work and then slowly converted it to manifest V3 one error message at a time.

Comment: @RussellHertel How did you fix `Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available`?

Comment: That probably has to do with the SDK. Go to this web page: "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js" or which ever you need such as firebase-database.js (you will need both). Right click on the page do save as to your project then put this at the top of your background.js: "importScripts('firebase/gstatic.com_firebasejs_8.10.0_firebase-app.js');
" for all that you have imported